# spring security oauth2 token is empty

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

Not quite sure why this is happening... please see this screenshot:
[oauth2_token_obtained_debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1eSg.png)

In GsonHttpMessageConverter.java:197, method writeInternal, I can see the OAuth2 token has been created and is being marshalled out.  However, the response that I am getting is an empty json body {}.  The database has the correct token in the oauth_access_token table.  I am just not getting it in the response.

I found a similar problem on the web but no answers to this issue:
https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth/issues/49

It appears that Gson writes nothing to the outputstream.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am still unable to use gson with OAuth2, the response body is empty.

What I did was remove gson from my dependencies and add Jackson 2.8.8.  It works now and I get the proper Json response.

I am not sure why gson does not do anything.  The code that is not working is GsonHttpMessageConverter:197

```
    @Override
protected void writeInternal(Object o, Type type, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {

    Charset charset = getCharset(outputMessage.getHeaders());
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputMessage.getBody(), charset);
    try {
        if (this.jsonPrefix != null) {
            writer.append(this.jsonPrefix);
        }
        if (type != null) {
            this.gson.toJson(o, type, writer);  // <-- this line DOES NOT write "o" of type DefaultOAuth2AccessToken to the OutputStreamWriter
        }
        else {
            this.gson.toJson(o, writer);  
        }
        writer.close();
    }
    catch (JsonIOException ex) {
        throw new HttpMessageNotWritableException("Could not write JSON: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```